# How remove gap between two image blocks in WP Bakery

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer, wpbakery

Hi there how can I remove white gap between images in link below? thanks
https://flashsystem.ir/product/haylou-x1-neo-earbuds/

WP Bakery settings didn't changed anything

Comment: Which gap do you mean?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a CSS expert, but i think you can do it by removing the margin in your css , from 35px to 0px.

```
.wpb_content_element, ul.wpb_thumbnails-fluid > li {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**before (35px)**
[image]

**after ( 0px )**
[image]

Comment: Thx for reply but I was talking about photos in description not gallery, here I marked it on this screenshot:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/uTg8DoMQ6HJn5WqT6

Comment: can u plz help me where can I use that code? I put it in extra css field of WPbakery block but didn't work also the block columns space is already 0 in the below screenshot, but still same.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/PU1ckHtjKKrb6Pye8

Comment: Ah thx found where I should put it. thanks so much❤